# Jquery Mobile - Strange question mark icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this strange problem with JQuery Mobile where I get a question mark icon displayed.

However if I refresh the page then it disappears!

Any ideas how to fix?

Here is my code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header"><h1>blah</h1></div>
<div data-role="content">
<br><br>
<a href="index.php" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="home" data-theme="b">Home</a>
<a href="cart.php" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="info" data-theme="b">View Basket</a>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ehu9v/

[image: Here is what is displayed in the browser]

This is displayed in the browser, refresh with f5 and the question marks go away.

Comment: Working as per fiddle. Which browser you checking on?

Comment: Chrome; Version 33.0.1750.117 m

Comment: Also goes wrong in Firefox :(

Comment: So what the heck is that?!

Comment: Also happens for me. Scary, I'm about to scrap jquery mobile, wondering if this is a very immature product thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an encoding issue. Try setting the encoding explicitly in your `<head>`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: What is your browser's encoding set to? https://help.yahoo.com/kb/yahoo-account/SLN14907.html?impressions=true

Answer (score 0):

I encountered that also and find out the reason, at the end... These are some weird unicode characters that appear as whitespace in any editor (Notepad++, etc) but as question marks in the browser.

They have probably been copied from jQuery Mobile website.